# Vue devtools updating but component isn't

Tags: vue.js, vuex

In my component I have:

```
currentItem.recipe
```

currentItem is a state in vuex initiated as object:

```
currentItem: {}
```

In the same component I import it with mapState:

```
...mapState('ItemStore', [
      'currentItem'
])
```

When I add a recipe for it, this mutation gets called:

```
ADD_ITEM_RECIPE: (state, recipe) => {
   state.currentItem.recipe = recipe
}
```

`recipe` is response from server to a post request to create a new recipe.

In my component I have some `v-if="currentItem.recipe"`, which is false at the beginning as `currentItem` has no `recipe`

The mutation get executed, in devtools I can see `recipe` being added to `currentItem`. But component does not update. The `v-if` does not change to true. In devtools, if I commit the mutation manually it works as expected.

So I tried to change the mutation to:

```
state.currentItem.recipe = Object.assign({}, state.currentItem.recipe, recipe)
```

but the problerm is still there.

Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to rewrite the entire object:

```
ADD_ITEM_RECIPE: (state, recipe) => {
   state.currentItem = {...state.currentItem, recipe: recipe}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're adding a new key to an existing object and as such reactivity doesn't work on that.

@HansFelixRamos answer is right, but you have also other alternatives.

1. You're `Object.assign` is close, but no cigar. You need to update the entire object.

   `state.currentItem= Object.assign({}, state.currentItem, {recipe})`

   This will add `recipe` to a new object, while shallow copying all the information from `state.currentItem`.
2. Another approach is to declare `recipe` on the state object from the start.

```
state: {
 currentItem: {
  //other properties 
  recipe: false // or null, or undefined
 }
}
```

I think the second approach is more suitable, especially for longer path object. If you declare default values for all keys you don't need to write defensive code like this `const val = obj && obj.path1 && obj.path1.path2 && obj.path1.path2.path3` to access deeply nested properties.